# Get all of the values below a specified value in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to get all the values in an array that are below the BigDecimal value specified by the user.   This is what I have so far:

```
class MyClass {
    public static void mymethod(BigDecimal[] values, BigDecimal uservalues) {
          for (int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++) {
              System.out.prinln(String.valueof(list.get(i)));
          }
    }
}
```

I'm not understanding the logic of how to do this.

So lets say `values` has the following values:

```
24.50
23.58
24.68
21.68
2.05
48.36

USER INPUT: 23

2.05
21.68
```

Hopefully my question is clear.  Could anyone provide any tips?

Comment: Are you *really* using `BigDecimal` in homework? I would have expected `double` or some such ..

Comment: Where is `list` defined? Do you have something that compiles yet (the code you posted won't compile)?

Comment: we need more examples of user input/output

Comment: are you just trying to print the values that are less than the given value, or are you trying to return an array of the values that are less than the given value?

Comment: @ryanbwork i am trying to print the values  that are less than the given value..tks

Comment: @pst ya really using it cause dealing with money and that is what advised to me..

Comment: You might want to also edit the other `list.get(i)` ;-)

Comment: By the way, it's 'capiche'.
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/capiche

Comment: @ShawnD. :) tks man..i am not ITalian..hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`NavigableSet.headSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#headSet%28E%29) :-)

> Returns a view of the portion of this set whose elements are strictly less than `toElement`.

This is likely an easier solution than manually iterating and using `compareTo`.

```
/* use this in place of an array */
final NavigableSet<BigDecimal> values = new TreeSet<BigDecimal>();
/* read from the user e.g. Scanner.nextBigDecimal() */
final BigDecimal ceiling = ...;
for (final BigDecimal lower : values.headSet(ceiling)) {
  /* lower will be less than ceiling */
}
```

Comment: You're talking about high level concepts and objects to a straight-up rookie...

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call it high-level but if you think the solution is too complex I should remind you that you're free to post your own :-) I don't see anything wrong with prompting him to delve into the Java API.

Comment: Think of it like this:  Using stuff on the API to get the task done in an entry level course is like starting a student driver out on the highway - they don't have the fundamentals down enough to appreciate what they're doing.

Comment: @veer hey man tks but i haven't been tot those at school but i have looked at ur solution and implemented it and also i am sure u know how these teachers are.. they dont like smart alec's.. so pls see my original question i have changed it..

Comment: @JackyBoi well according to [`Comparable.compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)), it __returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.__ Since you are interested in the numbers *less than* the user input, you want `acbalArray[i].compareTo(balinput) < 0`. Note that you can use an *enhanced `for` loop* to avoid tracking the array position e.g. `for (BigDecimal balance : acbalArray) { ... }`

Comment: @veer hey its like only displaying one value and on top of that it showing nullpointerexcepetion..pls assit i think we r on to something...regarding your enhanced for loop quite dont get it..

Comment: @JackyBoi can you tell me what the exception trace is?

Comment: @veer Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @JackyBoi can you show me the output of `printStackTrace`? Can you show me the entire code (on http://ideone.com/)

Comment: @veer hello sorry how to do printstacktrace? not sure

Answer (score 1):

As I think that this is homework, I will not give you the answer. But can tell you, that you will be interested in [`BigDecimal#compareTo(BigDecimal)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigDecimal%29). ;)

Oh and btw: It is **always** a good idea to look at the documentation of a class that you are using and are not familiar with it. Or if you work with an IDE like eclipse, you can just *use* autocomplete to give you a list of all possible methods.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- Your syntax is a bit off.  It should be `System.out.println`.
- `list` comes out of nowhere; I think you mean to use `values`.
- You're using an array; to access elements in an array, you use the index location as defined (which in your case is `i`).
- A hint:  If you find a value that is higher than what is specified, then skip it.  You would want to use [`BigDecimal.compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) to help accomplish that.  You'll also have to store the results somewhere, maybe a `String`?

Comment: hey makato, so i editied my question with the actual code  that i am working on..

Comment: @JackyBoi: Pay attention to what `compareTo()` returns - either a -1, 0, or 1.  Use these values to determine if the number is smaller than, the same as, or larger than your entered number.

Comment: http://ideone.com/GPD8V i posted my code here man.. can help me see what is that i am doing wrong u can find the above method(in my actual question) in the display() method..tks

Comment: @JackyBoi:  Sorry, I'm not here to debug your code - that'd be expensive for you ($30/hr) and expensive for me (I'm only here for fun, and it's near my bedtime).  If you're having troubles outside of the scope of this question, then please ask another one, and be *very specific* about the problem and what you've tried.

Comment: "that'd be expensive for you ($30/hr)" haha ok is that USD? cause i really have a question that i need to get done..

Comment: @JackyBoi:  That was tongue-in-cheek (although I really would charge that much to look at your code, it's not in the spirit of why I'm here at SO).  No, I'm not going to debug that code.  If you have another question to ask, then ask it in another question.  It really goes out of the scope of what this question is.